# Stop timer if Form is active

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

Is there a way that I can stop the timer if the user is using the current form, example, writing on a textbox. The reason for this is that every minute I make a refresh to the form ("Update data from Database") but if the user is writing on a text box and the timer gets to that minute it resets the textbox and the user has to write again, in other words it has approx. 1minute to finish writing on the form.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        SelectProgress();
    }
private void SelectProgreso()
    {

      try
         {

            OleDbDataReader reader;
            reader = oleDbCmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();

            progress= reader[1].ToString();

            int op = Int32.Parse(progress);
            switch (op)
            {
                case 1:
                    progressBar1.Value = 20;

                    button1.Enabled = false;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    progressBar1.Value = 40;

                    button1.Enabled = false;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    progressBar1.Value = 60;

                    button1.Enabled = false;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    progressBar1.Value = 80;


                    break;
                case 5:
                    progressBar1.Value = 100;

                    button1.Enabled = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Error");
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (OleDbException error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            mycon.Close();
        }
   }
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 WindowsForm.
Any help or comment on this is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach a second timer to the `TextChanged` etc. events of your interface together with a stop of the main timer.
The second timers tick event then starts the main timer back after a few seconds without input.

EDIT: Like so :)

```
    Timer mainTimer;
    Timer activityTimer;

    public Form1()
    {
        mainTimer = new Timer();
        activityTimer = new Timer();
        mainTimer.Interval = 60000;
        activityTimer.Interval = 2000;
        activityTimer.Tick += activityTick;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void activityTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mainTimer.Start();
        activityTimer.Stop();
    }

    private void onUserinput(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mainTimer.Stop();
        activityTimer.Stop();
        activityTimer.Start();
    }
```

Comment: I think a short code sample could be helpful to the OP.

Comment: Added it, hope it explains the way I thought of it ;)

Comment: Went with this option, tried making a function witch returns a bool if the any of the text inputs are different, but in some of my forms there aren't any of them since I'm using tabs with UC.@BradleyDotNet, still great advice for future problems thx.

Answer (score 1):

There's no *direct* way to do this, just as there is no direct way to determine if a `Form` is "active" (among other reasons, because "active" means different things to different people).

Some things you *can* do:

1. Don't make your editable controls update on the database refresh.
2. Stop the timer on user input, something like listening to all your control's `TextChanged` events.
3. Stop the timer on `Focus` events.

Note that whenever you stop the timer, you also need to define the logic that starts it *back up* (probably another timer!). Basically, you need to define what "active" and "inactive" actually mean, and code your logic against that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could add event handlers to all the relevant controls on the form that update a "lastEdited" field or something like that so that, when the timer goes off, you could check how long it's been since the last edit and only reload the data if it's been long enough.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could do is check to see if the textbox has focus before updating it, and then don't update it if it's got the focus.